# Benefit of Self-Contained Deployment for IIS?

Tags: iis, deployment, .net-core

Microsoft's documentation lists a benefit of doing a **Self-Contained Deployment** (SCD) is not having to install anything, including the .net core framework. But, I found out from other sources, that in order to actually use SCD on an IIS server, it is required to install the .net core hosting bundle...

I thought the point of self-contained deployment was that it was "self-contained". If I have to install something whether I'm doing a SCD, or doing Framework-Dependent deployment, then I would choose framework- dependent, because it is much smaller.

Is there a reason .net core hosting bundle needs to be installed on the IIS server? Can I find a way to not install it?

Comment: I have a feeling that the documentation is referring to deploying to unix/linux. Do you have a link to the documentation?

Comment: This is the documentation talking about deployment options, but i don't have the documentation where I learned that i needed the hosting bundle. That was more trial and error, and reading other articles. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index

Comment: SCD is almost useless if you deploy to Windows/IIS. The hosting bundle is always a must, as ASP.NET Core module can only be installed from it.

Comment: Alright, that's exactly what i wanted to know. Thanks. Just wanted to make sure i wasn't missing an obvious reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Aspnetcore applications can be hosted in IIS using two hosting models:

- **In-process hosting model**: IIS loads an aspnetcore runtime and the website assemblies in the worker process (w3wp.exe). Requests are processed by the in-memory runtime and responses and sent back to the client;
- **Out-of-process hosting model**: IIS runs the aspnetcore application in a separate process (dotnet.exe). The worker process (w3wp.exe) forwards requests to the external process and sends the responses to the client upon receiving them.

In both cases, IIS need to understand that the website is an aspnetcore application and how to manage it: load the in-process assemblies and runtime, and how to monitor, start, and proxy to the out-of-process application. This is the purpose of the [**aspnet core module** (ANCM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-8.0) which is an IIS module that runs within the IIS server worker process. Even when the aspnetcore application is self-contained, IIS needs that module, otherwise the requests wouldn't hit the aspnetcore application.

Installing the ANCM in IIS is the purpose of the **dotnet core hosting bundle**. But since IIS might need to host both self-contained and framework-dependent applications, it also installs a dotnet runtime on the server. Otherwise the server would crash when hit by a request of a framework-dependent application.

Note that when running out-of-process, the self-contained application uses it's own runtime version, which might differ from the runtime installed by the hosting bundle. Although not recommended you would be able to run a dotnet 8 self-contained aspnetcore application on a IIS server that has an outdated hosting bundle, provided it runs out-of-process. Please note, however, that "*hosting an aspnetcore application in-process delivers significantly higher request throughput compared to hosting the app out-of-process and proxying requests to Kestrel*".

I'm not sure what version of the runtime would be used when hosting a self-contained aspnetcore application in-process, but it sounds likely to use the hosting bundle's version.

If you need to run a self-contained application on a server that does not have the hosting bundle installed, you may configure IIS to run as a transparent proxy. However, doing so requires manual process management, which might turn up to be quite cumbersome. IIS is probably not the best tool for this use case, and you might want to take a closer look to containers / orchestration solutions such as docker and kubernetes.

Answer (score -1):

The self contained deployments do not contain the native dependencies for running a .NET core application, [see the first paragraph of this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index#self-contained-deployments-scd).

You can follow the native dependencies of .NET core to a github project that has the native prerequisites for windows, macOS and linux. [native prerequisites](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/prereqs.md)

Comment: It might be a useful answer for generic .NET Core apps, but not under IIS scenario and not for this specific question.